# Different keyboard layout in different windows

Tags: keyboard

How can I enable differend keyboard layout in different applications? Switch button in settings not working =(

Теперь по-русски =)
Как сделать свою раскладку для каждого окна? В юнити работало, в кедах работало, а затем я открыл для себя elementary, поставил, настроил смену раскладки, но вот меняется она глобально почему-то, хотя соответствующий тумблер в настройках включён

Comment: This is bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1444519

Answer (score -1):

Open system settings and click Keyboard:

[image]

Then click the Layout tab and change the slider:

[image]